# PHP _COOKIE not set despite it being set in the cookie header

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

I can't quite figure this out, I am setting a cookie as follows in my PHP code.

```
setcookie('remember', $sCookie, time()+31557600, '/');
```

And I can clearly see it in the headers

```
Cookie:__utma=144618662.427039340.1410986461.1413382878.1413400525.42; __utmz=144618662.1412022114.19.3.utmcsr=unknown|utmccn=embed|utmcmd=embed; _ga=GA1.2.427039340.1410986461; remember=J%15%1C%009F%F0%0F%E6%24%C9%26%04%A8%3Ej8gp%2FLXjVo3AlCzFvO6em5A%3D%3D; PHPSESSID=pjaso28lsfkt16e9takc3s6q42
```

But if I [`var_dump($_COOKIE)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) all I get is

```
array(4) {
    '__utma' => string(55) "144618662.427039340.1410986461.1413382878.1413400525.42"
    '__utmz' => string(66) "144618662.1412022114.19.3.utmcsr=unknown|utmccn=embed|utmcmd=embed"
    '_ga' => string(26) "GA1.2.427039340.1410986461"
    'PHPSESSID' => string(26) "pjaso28lsfkt16e9takc3s6q42"
}
```

Other info

- The domain is a development one, so the port is non-standard, 8888 instead of 80. As is the domain, commandstation.byl.dev.
- I am running the exact same code on byl.dev:8888 and it works without issue.
- If I look at the cookie info through a chrome plugin the host (commandstation.byl.dev) and  path (/) are right.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I could look next to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The value I was storing to the cookie (which FYI was generated with openssl_encrypt) was not compatible with cookies.

I base64 encoded the value after encrypting it and now it works fine. It was just a fluke that the encrypted string on the primary domain was acceptable, and for all I know it doesn't work for everyone so I will make the same fix there.